# Procedure for dual booting (2 copies of Win-7) off 2 partitions on same disk

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, multi-boot

What procedure should I follow to  set a dual boot (both Win-7 x64) on a machine where (ideally):

- Both operating systems will be installed on the same physical disk in different partitions
- When booting into either operating system the contents of the other OS partition disk will not be seen (this just seems safer)
- Other hard drives in the system will be visible by both OS's

1 copy of Win7 is already installed.

Is it as simple as shrinking the existing volume and creating the partition, then sticking the CD in and booting off it and formatting the new partition and then installing another copy of windows onto the new partition?  Or will that not work?  Or are there gotchas?

Comment: Hi I am thinking about doing the same thing so I was wondering if you could share whether this worked for you and if you had any unexpected problems. In my case the C drive already has English version of Win 7 Ultimate, another partition has Win XP and I want Win 7 in yet another partition but in a different language

Comment: I am asking because I want to do this with as little hassle as possible, and I don't want to end up having to format my C drive which has working copy of Win 7 already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just stick the CD in and install it on a separate partition to your first, it will automatically add the second operating system to the boot loader to. Although they might both have the same name at first (you can change the bootloader names from inside Windows)

Comment: Thanks. Just to note thoguh, by default you **can** see the other c:\ drive, it just appears as any other drive.

Comment: I'll remove that part from the answer, maybe that was an old XP thing.

Comment: @SamHolder - This is to be expected.  If you want to protect the data on each partition encrypt them.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't want to protect the data, just to avoid casual mistakes.  Removing the drive letter for the other machines c:\ drive is the way forward I think